# Sum of compositions of a number n ranging from k to k+m

Tags: combinatorics

This problem is about the sum of compositions of a ranging number n. Take n=3 and k=3. The composition of n into 3 parts (k=3) is (1,1,1). Then take n=n+1=4. Keep the k=3. The compositions of 4 into 3 parts are (1,1,2), (1,2,1), (2,1,1). Next increase the n again: n=n+1=5. The compositions of 5 into 3 parts are: (1,1,3), (1,2,2), (1,3,1), (2,1,2), (2,2,1), (3,1,1).
What is a formula for a sum of compositions, for a given, constant k, and n varying from k to k+m, m>0? This looks doable.
The number of compositions of n into exactly k parts (k-composition) is given by the binomial coefficient $\binom {n-1}{k-1}$. So the question is about the sum of these binomial coefficients. If k=3 and k+m=6, then the sum is $\binom {2}{2} + \binom {3}{2} + \binom{4}{2} + \binom {5}{2} = 20$.

Comment: Hint: $20 = { 6 \choose 3 }$ . Apply the hockey stick identity to your sum of binomial coefficients.

Comment: I think the answer is $\binom {6} {3}$. I will try to prove it.

Comment: I googled the term 'hockey stick identity' and this answers my question. Thank you for help.